# Export VertexAI Image Model

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai, google-cloud-automl

i have trained a image classification model using Vertex Ai from Google as edge model and also downloaded the container version.
But i don't know how i can deploy this to make predictions. I have read about deploying to a docker container but only found a tutorial by google for tabular data.
Do you have any tips or tutorials maybe on how to use the model to make predictions?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have two options to [get predictions from an image classification model](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/image-data/classification/get-predictions#get_batch_predictions).

- **[Online Predictions](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/image-data/classification/get-predictions#deploy_a_model_to_an_endpoint)**

> You must deploy a model to an endpoint before that model can be used to serve online predictions. Deploying a model associates physical resources with the model so it can serve online predictions with low latency.

- **[Batch Predictions](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/image-data/classification/get-predictions#get_batch_predictions)**

> You must select input and output locations that are in the same region as your model. If you use the API to create batch predictions, send requests to a service endpoint (such as https://us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com) that is in the same region as your input and output locations.